# Golang XML etree: Unexpected <></> when adding outer layer

Tags: xml, go, soap, xml.etree

I tried to add outer XML to my XML using golang library that is called https://github.com/beevik/etree
assume my XML is `<Foo></Foo>` but when trying to add the outer layer there's an additional empty tag like `<></>`
how to remove that?

Here's my snippet:
https://go.dev/play/p/z6E5Ha3hWmm

and the result is

```xml
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body/>
  <><Foo/></>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I expected the result is

```xml
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body/>
  <Foo/>
</soap:Envelope>
```

There's <></> between

**EDIT**
The `<Foo/>` is dynamic, so it can be `<Bar/>` or anything else

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I just need to add `.Root()`
So it should be `soapBody.AddChild(result.Root())`

https://go.dev/play/p/F84DOOGo0p-

Answer (score 0):

I'm far more familiar with etree than with golang, so you may have to take the following with a grain (or two) of salt (and re-write it), but you need to do a couple of basic xml-related things:

First, you have to wrap your `<Foo>` element in a root element to make it well formed xml document and then, inside that document, select that element.

Second, in the second (`root`) document, select the location where you want the `<Foo>` element to be added and then add it.

So it should look like this:

```
    result := etree.NewDocument()
    root := etree.NewDocument()

    root.ReadFromString("<soap:Envelope><soap:Header/><soap:Body/></soap:Envelope>")
    result.ReadFromString("<root><Foo/></root>")

    source := result.FindElements("//Foo")[0]
    destination := root.FindElements("//soap:Envelope")[0]

    destination.AddChild(source)
```

See [the updated snippet here.](https://go.dev/play/p/n3TvwMQWdBX)

Comment: actually `<Foo/>` is dynamic, so It is not always foo, I think we cannot use `FindElements` here

Comment: @DavidAsync Well, you didn't mention it in the question... Nonetheless, it may still be possible to use `FindElements` after the element name is dynamically created, though I'm not sure how. Maybe you should present that issue as a separate question.

Comment: sorry I have editted the question, by the way. I already find out the answer. Turns out I only need to add .Root()

Comment: @DavidAsync As they say - all's well that ends well!